# Changing Background Color of UILabel

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

Good Day! i just want to ask if how can i change the background color of a UILabel depending on the number typed on it? e.g if the number is 0 it's Blue and if the number is 1-2 it will became green. And if the number is 3-4 it will become orange. thank you for your answers!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: i want to change the Background Color of a Label depending on what number it shows.

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: i tried this.. but im getting errors, i put this under ViewDidLoad http://oi43.tinypic.com/11gkto1.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UITextFieldDelegate` does not have a didChange method. You will have to manually add behaviour. You can use the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method, but personally I would  advise not to override methods unless you absolutely have to.

```
[yourTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Then, in the target method, set the background color with:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange{

    if ([yourTextField.text isEqualToString:@"1"] || [yourTextField.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
        yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    else if (...)
        .
        .
        //and so on
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set like this...

```
int number = [yourLbl.text intValue];

if(number == 0)
    yourLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
else if(number == 1 || number == 2)
    yourLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
else if(number == 3 || number == 4)
    yourLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
else
    yourLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: He is talking about **background color**. not text color.\

Comment: for background color, it will be `[yourLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIcolor greenColor]];`

Comment: What error u getting ?

Comment: im getting this error http://oi43.tinypic.com/11gkto1.jpg

Comment: @LevisBotio now see my edited answer.

Comment: i tried it but im only getting blue colors even the number is higher than zero

Answer (score 0):

you can't type on a UILabel, use UITextField

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
      int number = [textField.text intValue];
      if(number == 0) {
           label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
      } else if(number == 1 || number == 2) {
           label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
      } else if(number == 3 || number == 4)
           label.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
      }


     return YES;
}
```

Comment: a single digit number

Comment: my label is getting its number based on the result of the calculations so im not typing on it

Answer (score 0):

First Convert your label text number to **int**, than use **backgroundColor** for label background.

```
int number = [yourLabel.text intValue];

if(number == 0)
    yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
else if(number == 1 || number == 2)
    yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
else if(number == 3 || number == 4)
    yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
else
    yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this condition, inside textfielddidendedition

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if(label.text isEqualToString:0)
{
   label.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
 }
else
{
label.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
}
}
```

Comment: Direct comparison with `==` is not valid when you are comparing object values. And with strings you can have two strings that are the same, but they are different objects, in this case your comparison will fail. Also, you are checking a string against a number, so I doubt this even compiles. Also, what happens if there are spaces in the input, or for 0.0? or -0?